# Is it necessary to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider() to generate random number from 0 to 9?

Tags: vb.net, security, random

Our current code of generate a random number from 0 to 9 is:

```
Int(10 * Rnd())
```

It works perfect ! but we are wondering, will the code cause some insecure randomness security issues ?

So is it necessary to use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` to generate random number from 0 to 9 ?

Comment: how random do you need your number to be? Context: what hinges on this number? If you think you do refer to the rolldice implementation on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx an dmodify it to you rneeds.

Comment: The code you have is fine for VB6 but if you're writing VB.NET code then you should be using the `Random` class. You only need to use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class if you need a higher level of security. As you haven't bothered to tell us what you're using this for, there's no way that we can judge whether that's required.

Comment: From a security POV, the point of generating random numbers is them being unpredictable. A number between 0 and 9 is too small to satisfy that condition as all variations can be attempted in less than a second.

Comment: @Narf A number 1-6 is random enough to bet billions of $ on, it depends on the usage. See [craps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps), Las Vegas and 0-36 for roulette.

Comment: @zaph Which is why I started by noting that I'm talking about security, as implied by the suggestion to use a CSPRNG.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on your needs**

If you require this number to be as random as physically possible, then yes you should use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` class.

If this is just a random number for something seemingly trivial, then it's not really necessary that it uses this class. For example, if you are just trying to calculate a random number for something temporarily then it should be just fine.

For example, if you're generating a user's password, you should generate the salt using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` as it needs to be as secure as possible. However, if you're making a "Roll the dice" game or a "Guess the number" game, then it's much easier to just use `Random()` as it isn't a high security risk.

Comment: Rephrase "entirely secure" to "as random as possible", a number can not be secure or not, it is the process that creates the number that is secure or not and to what degree. See XKCD [Random Number](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: @zaph Edited. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the needs of your program, if you actually need cryptographically secure randomness then yes, if your needs aren't that stringent then no.